# react-native run-ios Build Failed

Tags: react-native

react-native run-ios
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/qitmac000495/Documents/个人Demo/QTalkFeatures/qtalk_lilu/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTWebSocket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTWebSocket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSRWebSocket.o RCTSRWebSocket.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

How I fix it? Xcode 8 and MacOS Sierra 10.12

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynHPj.jpg)

Comment: Nope，that can't make it.

Comment: refer to the accepted answer on this question to get more info stackoverflow.com/questions/38780325/… .